# normal distribution calculation error - Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r, excel, normal-distribution, probability-density

I have 2 data frames and I am applying `pnorm()` and `qnorm()` on the dataframe, but I am getting the errors, while calculating.

```
n <- c(0.3,0.5,0.1,0.2)
m <- c(0.1,0.4,0.5,0.3)
o <- c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4)
p <- c(0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3)
df1 = data.frame(n,m,o,p)
df1

  n   m   o   p
1 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.3
2 0.5 0.4 0.2 0.1
3 0.1 0.5 0.2 0.3
4 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.3
r <- c(0.2,0.4,0.1,0.3)

df2 = rbind.data.frame(r)
df2

  X2   X4  X1  X3
1 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.3

b <- 0.15

result <- pnorm((qnorm(df1)+sqrt(b)*df2)/sqrt(1-b))
Output: 
Getting an error: 
Error in qnorm(df1) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Expected output:

```
Output: 
0.3139178   0.110853    0.1919158   0.3289671
0.5334785   0.4574897   0.1919158   0.1031127
0.0957727   0.5667216   0.1919158   0.3289671
0.2035948   0.3442989   0.4079641   0.3289671
```

actually I have these 2 data-frames df1 and df1 and in excel and I have a formula in excel which I need to convert into R.

```
=NORMSDIST((NORMSINV(A1)+SQRT(0.15)*H1)/SQRT(1-0.15))
```

here A1 is the df1 first value and so on and H1 is the df2 value and so on.

Comment: `qnorm` requires vector of probabilities and you're trying to pass `df1` which is a `data.frame`

Comment: Just type `?qnorm` in your console to see the info.

Comment: please explain, i dont have any other option i have to pass this df1 can code something  to help me.

Comment: actually these 2 data frame df1 and df1 and in excel and i have a formula in excel which i need to convert it into R.  =NORMSDIST((NORMSINV(A1)+SQRT(0.15)*H1)/SQRT(1-0.15)) - - -> here A1 is the df1 first value and so on and H1 is the df2 value and so on ...

Comment: A1 is the df1 values, in excel all the df1 values are in rows and columns. same is with H1, H1 is df2 values first cell of H column has the df2 first item.

Comment: yes this the issue, how can i resolve it.

Comment: can you please write it so that i can understand .... bit confusing

Comment: let me edit my question in a better way with the expected output, then you can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is: apply a function to every row in `df1`. To do so we need to write a function.

```
getDist <- function(x, b = 0.15) {
    pnormInput <- as.numeric((qnorm(as.numeric(x)) + sqrt(b) * df2) / sqrt(1 - b)) 
    pnorm(pnormInput)
}
```

Next we apply this function to every row in `df1` (using `apply`).

```
result <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) getDist(x))
```

Next we have to transpose `result` (flip the table we got).

```
result <- t(result)
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.3139178 0.1108530 0.1919158 0.3289671
# [2,] 0.5334785 0.4574897 0.1919158 0.1031127
# [3,] 0.0957727 0.5667216 0.1919158 0.3289671
# [4,] 0.2035948 0.3442989 0.4079641 0.3289671
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it is working fine with small datasets...let me try on n number of columns

Comment: @RS ok, let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a classic case of trying to do many operations in one line and losing track of what every function is doing. My answer is essentially the same as @PoGibas', but a bit more explicit and less elegant.

I'll calculate the terms separately and then combine them again afterwards:

```
num1 <- apply(df1, 1, qnorm)       # Apply 'qnorm' row-wise
num2 <- sqrt(b) * r                # Add the constant sqrt(b) to vector r

num <- sweep(num1, 1, num2, "+")   # Add the vector num2 row-wise to the dataframe num2
den <- sqrt(1-b)                   # den is a constant

result <- pnorm(num/den)           # num is a data frame, which is elementwise divided by the constant den.
t(result)
```

By doing the operations step-by-step, you will often have a much easier time finding the source of an error.